# npm run build in tailwind css with multiple html pages

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, tailwind-css

I run npm run build and dist folder was created but when I open that I not get my other html files and after run that it only showing simple html not included css and it not have my other files I connected to that like about.html contact.html

Answer (score 0):

create `input.css` file in src folder then build `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/output.css">` include about and contact html page then open
tailwind.config.js file and use

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{html,js }" ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./contact.html", "about.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
```

}